# Having a view with a TabBar without any of the tab views showing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, tabbar

Is it possible to have a UITabBar with lets say 2 tab bar items, but the view being shown not one that is part of the tab bar?

for instance I have orange view with the tab bar at the bottom, on the tab bar there is blue view button and green view button and the only way to see the green or blue views would be a user interaction to the tab bar. otherwise it will always display orange view.

Sorry if this is confusing, and how would I implement this in code?

Comment: Perhaps you want to push a VC onto a navigation controller, and have the navigation controller as one of the tab bar's VCs?

Comment: Because it gives me the ability to have one working space, while also having somewhat of an interrupt to two other important views. tc's idea sounds good, ill have to try it in code.

Comment: Won't it irritate users that they can't get back to the orange view?

Answer (score 0):

This will almost certainly get your app rejected with the reason "this might lead to customer confusion".

UITabBarController is meant to show different sections of one app, not to affect a single view. Instead for this you want to use a UIToolbar.